# Postgresql hangs?

Tags: php, database, postgresql, pdo

My postgresql hangs time to time.
I used this query

```
SELECT
  datname, 
  NOW() - query_start AS duration, 
  pid, 
  query 
FROM
  pg_stat_activity 
WHERE
    query <> '<IDLE>'
  AND
    NOW() - query_start > '1 second'
ORDER BY duration DESC;
```

and found this:

```
query: DEALLOCATE pdo_stmt_00000009
duration: 00:00:43.879915
```

such query can hangs for 1-2 minutes (but not every request, randomly). And script waits for it

And its no locks. Checked with query:

```
select * from pg_locks where not granted;
```

It appears from time to time after small insert command:

```
INSERT INTO requests (val1, val2, val3, val4) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
```

I tried not to use PDO, tried not to use transaction (without transaction) but its not helps.

So, any ideas?

Comment: For pg 9+ [that's normal behavior](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAFwQ8rfvsRe0XJt6F=TS6TB0=02xshTK_TNE=BkDa2SO4wQJPQ@mail.gmail.com) - can you elaborate a bit more on how you define "hangs"? Are you sure it's not just working on a complicated, long query? It may also help to increase logging (eg, `log_min_duration_statement` in the config file) to gain more insight in what the server is actually doing at any moment,

Comment: My application hangs, because of insert query isnt end, untill this "DEALLOCATE" ends

Comment: For an idle connection, `pg_stat_activity` will show the most recent query. Check for `state = 'active'` to see which queries are actually running.

Comment: Enable `log_checkpoints` and see how long checkpoints are taking. Check the logs for warnings about checkpoints occurring too frequently too.

Comment: I am recently encountering similar problem when updating thousands of records in one PHP CLI script run. The script finishes its job but it still looks like it is doing something. While this is happening, there is a Postgres process running DEALLOCATE. Until this process finishes, the PHP script won't stop. Putting exit() to the end of script changes nothing. But when I break the script by CTRL+C, the records are just fine.